# PreferenceActivity subclass should not be exported in the manifest (ExportedPreferenceActivity)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-manifest

Android Studio is throwing a lint warning saying

```
PreferenceActivity subclass com.myapp.app.SettingsActivity should not be 
exported in the manifest

Inspection info:Fragment injection gives anyone who can send your 
PreferenceActivity an intent the ability to load any fragment, with any 
arguments, in your process.  Issue id: ExportedPreferenceActivity
```

I've never actually noticed when this warning started appearing, but I can't find a way to fix it without breaking the activity. SettingsActivity is an `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` with two `PreferenceFragments` and gets created after a SplashScreen. I've tried setting `android:exported="false"` in my Manifest.xml already, but it gives an error because action.VIEW cannot have export turned off.

Relevant Manifest.xml code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

don't expose it with a launcher (which sounds alike what it complains about):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible remove:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you can't remove all of it just delete this line:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```